# Is Brahmacharya biggest virtue in a man?

Tags: women, sex, men

In case of women , being Pativrata is considered as biggest virtue. Just by being Pativrata , she not only reserves her place in heaven (with her husband) for crores of years but also protects her husband from death even in this life.

I want to know if being a Brahmachari , is considered as equivalent virtue in men.

Note - Brahmachari doesn't mean unmarried . One can be married and still be brahmchari i.e. engaging in sex even with wife only for procreation.

Answer (score 0):

the highest virtue of all living entities is prapatti. "sarva dharman paritajya mam ekam sharanam vraja" (gita chapter 18 verse 66). there are 5 angas of prapatti as per ramanujacharya. 1. accepting the inability to perform bhakti,gyan and karma yoga and accepting prapatti as the only path to liberation.2. wish of  doing those works that pleases lord narayana. 3. wish of not doing those works that displeases lord hari. 4 to have no other wish except liberation. 5. to have firm faith that lord narayana will definitely grant liberation.

Answer (score -1):

It is just a stage in life out of 4 stages of life. Considering it as Virtue is left to individuals because society framework of elevating Brahmacharya is very rare.

It is the most happiest stage in life with peaceful mind that might have achieved the goal of "purpose of life" before entering next stage : grihasta(Family-Asset creator) / vanaprasta(Divine traveller) which may be only KARMIC & mutual depending upon generations.